# Programming an iTunes script for converting a playlist

Tags: applescript, itunes

I have a gigantic playlist (around 2000 songs) in iTunes that I would like to convert to 320 kbps MP3 (from low-quality AAC). What I want to do is convert all the songs in the playlist, delete the low-quality originals, and then re-import the songs into the playlist (as iTunes recognizes the converted songs as new songs and the deleted originals obviously do not remain). Seeing as Automator's default scripts for doing this are broken in iTunes 9, how would I write an Apple Script to handle this task?

I would like to avoid the painful: doing this manually, if I can help it. Thanks.

Comment: You do realize what you're trying to do makes no sense. Basically you have "low-quality" songs. Re-encoding them at a higher bit rate will not improve their quality. They're low quality to begin with and you can't end up with better quality than the original source. Actually you will just degrade them further because every time you encode something you lose quality.

Comment: Why can't you improve the quality? Following your logic, the highest-quality files are processed from sources in high-quality format? Thus, deleting the low-quality tracks and re-importing the CDs as 320 kbps MP3 would accomplish what I want?

Comment: Exactly Lucius. When something is compressed, you throw away information from the original source. That's how you make a file smaller. So your "low quality" songs already have a lot of information missing (lost) from the original music. You can never get that back. That's why there's lossy and lossless compression. AAC encoding as well as MP3 encoding is lossy. All you can do is lose more information by recompressing them. This job requires you to re-import from the CD.

Answer (score 0):

wow I didn't know they took away the ability to convert songs to other formats that stinks. You may be able to find a better answer at [Doug's applescripts for itunes](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/) baring that you'll have to use some other software that will handle the conversion task which will hopefully be easy or powered by applescript and then use applescript to reomve the old verisons from itunes and put the new ones in

Comment: Apple did not remove the ability to convert songs to other formats. About what you are saying: yes, that is what I want to do (I thought the question was obvious)...

Comment: the question is obvious I just don't have a direct solution for you

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention you’re using iTunes 9, you do still have the ability to use mp3 as your default. (I haven’t looked at iTunes 10; I suspect the same works there.)

1. Go to iTunes:Preferences…
2. Choose Import Settings (next to “When you insert a CD”)
3. Choose Import Using MP3 Encoder
4. For Setting, choose Custom, and for Stereo Bit Rate, choose 320 kbps.

Despite being next to the CD settings, the Import Settings are for all conversions. Your Advanced menu’s convert item will change from AAC to MP3. So you can select all of your songs, convert them, and then delete the AAC versions.

Unless I’m missing something (it sounds like you only have one playlist, and you just want to convert all songs in that playlist), you wouldn’t need a script for this.

Comment: Converting a playlist is done more easily from the library page. If it's done in the playlist, the encoding will still occur, but then you must go into the library page and delete the originals. Deleting these lower-quality originals removes these songs from the playlist; the new songs must then be re-imported. This is three steps, not one. Also, I already did what you mention. I'm asking for an Apple script, not a basic guide to encoding.